# How to open or import .sdc files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-formats, smart-data-compression

I have some .SDC files i want to look at but i dont have arcview installed. is it possible?

i couldnt even find a software that does sdc to shp conversion.

any idea?

i am using qgis 1.7.4 on both windows and linux, i googled to find a converting software with no luck.

i think i am missing something since sdc is very popular and i could not find enough questions on this subject.

Comment: .sdc are an ESRI file format. As far as i'm aware you can't import them into QGIS. There may be a way to convert .SDC to .shp files or something more readable, i'll have a look around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.sdc files are ESRIs Smart Data Compression format that is optimized for fast display. Smart Data Compression is a proprietary format. I couldn't find any way of converting SDC files to shapefiles for use in an Open Source GIS such as Quantum but i did find reference of a conversion tool at http://www.lib.ncsu.edu/gis/formats.html called "Data Distribution Application" which can convert from .sdc to .shp, however I am assuming this is proprietary also. It might also be possible with Arc Catalog as the Help file suggests "ArcGIS provides conversion tools that let you convert SDC data to shapefiles and other formats." although that information is slightly vague.

My end thoughts are it is most probably not possible without ESRI software. Is there any way you can get the same data in .shp file format?