# Opening .sdc file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, smart-data-compression

I am using the newest version of QGIS (3.6.0 NOOSA) and I am trying to open a .sdc file that I extracted from an ESRI layer package.

Does anyone know if it is possible to open this type of file in the new version of QGIS or alternatively, if there is a plugin that converts from .sdc to .shp?

Comment: Not in QGIS because it uses GDAL "Driver can't read data in SDC format (Smart Data Compression) because operation is not supported by the ESRI SDK."  https://gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24662/how-to-open-or-import-sdc-files-in-qgis (2012)